# Particular solution to linear congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Suppose $ax\equiv b (\bmod m)$, then how to determine the number of solutions $x$ such that $gcd(x,m)=d$? Let us assume $gcd(a,m)|b$. I think euler totient function has some role here?Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try solving the congruence equation.

1. Dividing by $s=gcd(a,m)$ might help:

$ax \equiv b \pmod m  \Longleftrightarrow a'x \equiv b' \pmod{ m'}$.

Here 
$$
\begin{cases}
m's &= m,\\
a's &= a,\\
b's &= b.
\end{cases}
$$

2. [Invert $a'\pmod{m'}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) so that the equation is equivalent to 
   $$
   x\equiv b' c \pmod{ m'}
   $$
   Here $c$ is the $\pmod {m'}$ invere of $a'$.

So your problem translates to finding how many integers t satisfy
$$
gcd(b'c + t m' , m's) = d.
$$
If $t \equiv r\pmod s$, $0\leq r < s$ then $gcd(b'c + t m' , m's) = gcd(b'c + rm',m's)$.

So $gcd(b'c + t m' , m's)$ has at most $s$ different values and

***either there are infinitely many solutions $x$ of $gcd(x,m)= gcd(b'c + t m' , m's)=d$ or there is none.***